# asp.net mvc, IIS, threads, etc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-8

net experts.

There is a question that me and my colleagues cannot find an answer that would satisfy all of us.

On out web-site which is always has a heavy load we need to run some long running tasks asynchronously (image processing, cache building, ...). The initial implementation was using a `Thread` object for each such requests. I thought that use might be an overkill and it also can happen the situation when no more threads can be created. I took the approach to use the 'Task.Run' for all such request which behind the scene is using the ThreadPool.

I was told that this is not good either because the `IIS Application Pool` is using the `ThreadPool` by itself and there might be the situation when those background tasks would block to serve the usual HTTP request, which is also true.

What approach is best to be taken here: `Threads` or `Task`?

I know that the best would be to extract all this into a Windows Service and some kind of queue, but for time being we cannot do this.

Any other opinion are highly welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: Move whatever long running things out of ASP.NET to separate Windows service or Azure worker role and you will save yourself tons of efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Simple background threads is the best way for long-running tasks in the ASP.NET environment.

```
System.Threading.ThreadStart threadStart = delegate { SomeJob(someData); };
System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(threadStart);
thread.IsBackground = true;
thread.Start();
```

If you prefer using it encapsulated into `Task`, you can implement your own `TaskScheduler` which queues tasks using background threads instead of using ThreadPool, see example on MSDN - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.

For the long running tasks that are initiated from inside HTTP Handler, there is also an option to use asynchronous HTTP handlers, see an example here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227433.